# using or not using rsync with backup option

Tags: rsync, backup

I would like some feedback about the --backup option in rsync.  Is it worth using it for backups, or should I just use `rsync` commands that just transfer files without the use of --backup option?

```
-b, --backup      make backups (see --suffix & --backup-dir)
--backup-dir=DIR  make backups into hierarchy based in DIR
--suffix=SUFFIX   backup suffix (default ~ w/o --backup-dir)
```

Comment: It seems you're asking for an *opinion* instead of an answer. Perhaps work through `man rsync` to determine which is best for you.

Comment: I am trying to see of any advantages of using `--backup` since I do not have experience using it.

Comment: I understand... but aren't advantages dependent on the specifics of your use-case? It seems to be a case of ease-of-use (`--backup`) vs. a more "tailored" config. If you're happy with the "package" offered w/ `--backup` then it's likely your best choice.

Comment: Instead of asking these questions about `rsync`, it's best to check out the `man` page as was suggested in your other questions and actually use the command with your data so that you can see what happens and what you do and don't need. That's the only way that you're going to find out.

Comment: I am hesitant to use it because with the backup option, preexisting destination files are renamed as each file is transferred or deleted. It also says that previously  backed-up  files could get deleted.  Thusly I need some assistance understanding all the pros and cons.

Comment: Then set up some data that you don't care about or use it with data that's backed up or do a dry run with `rsync` that won't alter any data and will show you what will happen. You can find out how to do all of this with the `man` page and try it yourself. That's much more effective than asking people over the internet what will or won't happen with your data that people know nothing about.

Comment: My guess is that many don use the option.